# On vs in + place

Tags: meaning, phrases, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I've heard two different songs from two different performers, they go as:

> I'm inclined to waste my time in the avenues tonight

and

> Another night down on the avenues.

Both versions are correct since they both were used by native speakers, but I can not find subtle difference between two sentences. What is the difference when one says on avenues and in avenues but both in the context of place? 
And is it appropriate to say *at the avenues* what would be the difference?

Comment: I think it's more common to use *on* when talking about a specific street, e.g. *on Fifth Avenue*. When referring to avenues as a collective, I don't think there's much difference between *on* and *in*.

Comment: And what about at?

Comment: *at* is usually used for a more specific place, not a street. You can say "at the corner of Hollywood and Vine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What on Earth makes you thing all native speakers of any language always get it right?

```
I'm inclined to waste my time in the avenues tonight    
and
```

Another night down on the avenues

```
are simply not comparable.
```

They share pretty-much nothing but ‘the avenues’ 
Did you notice that ‘I can not find subtle difference between two sentences’ is certainly not what you meant?

You might have meant ‘I do not understand…’ and what makes you think that is anything like the same thing?

Please carefully note, when one says 'on avenues and in avenues but both in the context of place,' one is clearly confused; OK?

There is no difference between *in* or *on* the avenues.
It’s very difficult to imagine any circumstance in which it might be appropriate to think of you or I or anyone else being *at* the avenues…

All that Barmar says is wholly right and *at, in* and *on* are perfectly interchangeable, with or without the ‘down’ depending on the circumstances.

```
… down at the avenues
… down in the avenues
… down on the avenues
```

are clearly interchangeable in most circumstances and that doesn't change the fact that the examples you posted are in no relevant way comparable…